# Buttermilk / Cream Cheese glaze – food safety

Tags: food-safety, buttermilk, cream-cheese, glaze

I am baking some cinnamon rolls for a party. The glaze consists of cream cheese, powdered sugar and buttermilk.

Since the party will be held outside, I am a bit worried about food safety here. What will happen to the glaze after being out of the fridge for a few hours? Will it be safe to eat, maybe even the day after?

Comment: Yes it's safe. I mean what else could go wrong. The ingredients used should not develop any bacteria or any other unwanted organism. You should be fine .. No worries

Comment: @JohnReese But I am wondering: Since the glaze contains cream cheese, couldn't it get "sour"? Or does the high sugar content might act as a kind of preservative?